OTEL tracing Spans not shown in grafna
I am trying to do manual instrumentation with fastapi.
I see span info printed if I print to console , but its not showing in grafana. , only one of the span is missing, but others I am able to see.
Other issue is span names are not getting printed in grafana,
I am starting spans in this way
with tracer.start_as_current_span("create_embeddings") as span:


Here span names are missing to show in tables , and one of the span with name buddy is not present in table.
Env info

I am using OTEL collector
Python Fastapi application


Your left window is the list of traces. Grafana shows only 3 spans in the list. When you open the trace you will see all spans which belong to this trace.

if I click on trace also I dont see

How do you send traces to tempo? Do you use grafana agent?
